# Unable to execute gcloud Command in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, gcloud

I have admin access to a Security Command centre and a read-only access to a project. When I execute the following command, `gcloud scc findings list projects/<project name>`, I get the following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.scc.findings.list) PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller does not have required permission to use project <>. 

Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, 
by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=itsec-poc and then retry. 
Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes. 

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.
Help links: 
- description: Google developer console IAM admin url: https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=itsec-poc 
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo domain: googleapis.com metadata: consumer: projects/ <project Name> service: securitycenter.googleapis.com reason: USER_PROJECT_DENIED

$ gcloud scc findings list projects/<project name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it means a read-only access to a project isn't enough to run the command you're attempting to execute.

It's saying you need the role, `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer`.

Only the admin of the project can assign roles to your user